# how do I do a value count for items inside a list in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to below:

```
item
[chicken, duck, pig]
[pig, pig, duck]
[chicken, chicken, chicken]
[duck, horse, frog]
```

for this column, I want to do a value count of each items inside the list, the return should look like this

```
chicken 4
duck 2
pig 3
horse 1
frog 1
```

I used `df['items'].value_counts()`, but it only counts the list. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You can `.explode()` the dataframe and then do `.value_counts()`

Comment: Does the dataframe have 1 column with e.g. [chicken, duck, pig] as a string? Or 3 columns?